# Allow spring boot to start with failing health check

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, spring-boot-actuator

I have spring boot 2.2 with actuator running fine, but have a requirement for JMS to be down at startup and reconnect at a Later point in time.

If JMS is down, the app will fail to start due to the health check, but disabling JMS check in the config file means the check is never available.

Does anyone know a s9lution for this? Cheers

Comment: Don't add the JMS to your health check at beginning and add a logic that adds JMS to your health check Only if JMS status changed from disconnected to connected.

Comment: Where would this happen, and how would I reset the actuator config.